# SyntaxError: Unexpected number when pulling JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull the `IncPubKey` JSON data from "0", but I'm getting a SyntaxError. In postman, part of the returned data looks like this:

```
 "ShardCommittee": {
  "0": [{
        "IncPubKey": "12RRMGAEXdtD796sbmyHwNv9oiPPfGYa1r6KssMqXyiUMfT6r86",
        "MiningPubKey": {
          "bls": "184UyUYNPg1ESgEXzUZY6dWjxohyZSvE4f5XnkssHhonRNopAp2bxqxCAToYGUsgeyrWeKQJmnLkgeCm95XYK5mjD2KjFPKkrrwLyiXscUAJ9mVubTCft4Z1ra3S9Ca4ojx1P5ajMNaS2Yc9C1rh8qr2S7VE6KCk7YMnBpdkyWdiTrmGtUUjx",
          "dsa": "16Be2DoUxNMzxidLKBqDC6gMkqMZ9bSijBvpRirvioZiqmVGDkg"
        }
      },
      {
        "IncPubKey": "1VVQRGZFhMyp9LRS1yjyXsW6ugMqtHaYyUYMLutRhy6ASF7AWf",
        "MiningPubKey": {
          "bls": "1ELnsFdz5M4RDvShVvcAKE4bbv6dZED31MeSKgRKhDiYgTiJeWT94zvw2VHeytVxEDExMeemPqXL7DA1CnNBGbjTMarv1vXd1A6oi5JctfM4u8Totjpqr8VNFtQbgHqJ1wSYdFz5hgwEq8QkmDdf71WPPdYEkpG5ow3DYeAAwFkArQZvn1C4F",
          "dsa": "18BTfn7mbDBXgysaHZsrGqbN3T2K3gEChsEXXuzkwKEo96eU3Nf"
        }
      },
```

But in google, it doesn't seem to like the number "0."

```
  for (let i = 0; i < d.Result.ShardCommittee.0.length; i++) {
 sh1.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue(d.Result.ShardCommittee.0[i].IncPubKey);

}
```

When I step back and pull all data into one cell:

```
 sh1.getRange(2, 3).setValue(d.Result.ShardCommittee);
```

This is the returned result:

```
{ 0=[Ljava.lang.Object;@41d079f7,  1=[Ljava.lang.Object;@7197d9a6, 2=[Ljava.lang.Object;@23a1916a, 3=[Ljava.lang.Object;@657f1624, 4=[Ljava.lang.Object;@c3808bd, 5=[Ljava.lang.Object;@186f5f86, 6=[Ljava.lang.Object;@60f6425c, 7=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6cc43c2c}
```

Any idea how to re-write that to pull the `IncPubKey` data?

Comment: bad practise to have numeric keynames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a number as a key in "dot" notation, instead use array style notation:

```
Result.ShardCommittee["0"].length;
```

and

```
d.Result.ShardCommittee.["0"][i].IncPubKey
```

This is a javascript syntax issue, rather than a Google Apps Script specific issue.

in your last example, where you write the entire object to a cell, you are seeing the results of converting the structure to a string. If you want to write raw objects to a cell in the spreadsheet for inspection, you should convert them to JSON first.

```
 sh1.getRange(2, 3).setValue(JSON.stringify(d.Result.ShardCommittee));
```